Segmentation fault when copying tokens to struct fields using strcpy in C function with strtok
I'm developing a C function to read a single line from a text file, split it into tokens using strtok, and assign each token to specific fields in a struct. However, I'm encountering a segmentation fault when copying one of the tokens to a struct field using strcpy. Here's the code:

void readEnregFromTextFile(char *fileName, Tenreg *buffer) {
    char string[256];  // Buffer to hold a line from the file
    char *delimiters = ",|;\n";
    FILE *f = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        return;
    }

    if (fgets(string, sizeof(string), f) != NULL) {
        char *token = strtok(string, delimiters);
        if (token != NULL) {
            strcpy(buffer->name, token);  // Copy first token to name
            token = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
            if (token != NULL) {
                strcpy(buffer->departement, token);  // Error occurs here
                token = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
                if (token != NULL) {
                    buffer->salary = atof(token);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        printf("Error reading from file\n");
    }

    fclose(f);
}

the buffer structure is :
typedef struct {
    char *name  ; 
    char *departement ; 
    float salary ; 
}

*the buffer is not allocated  , it is just passed as a pointer so it's value can be modified , it is declared in the main as  Buffer buffer
Issue
When the function executes strcpy(buffer->departement, token);, I encounter a segmentation fault. After debugging, I found that the error occurs specifically at this line in the C code. The assembly output shows the error in the line:
mov    0xb8(%rbp),%rax    

here is the call in the main for my function
Buffer  buffer .
readEnregFromTextFile ("employee_data" , &buffer) ; 

I attempted to replace strcpy with strdup, and the function worked without issues. However, I'd like to understand why strcpy is causing a segmentation fault and whether there's a fundamental issue with my code structure.
Question
Why does strcpy cause a segmentation fault in this case, while strdup works?
How should I correctly handle token assignment in this situation?
Any insights would be appreciated!

You forgot to show what buffer is and how it was allocated.

In most cases you can replace strcpy with strncpy to prevent overflow.

@stark: Using strncpy() is not a magic solution — it has its place, but it is not a good solution much of the time.

Using my crystal ball:
If strdup works and strcpy doesn't it means that the buffer->departement is:

NULL, wild or not initalized pointer.
memory referenced is not large enough to accommodate the string

strdup allocates new memory and returns a pointer to that memory.
The remedy:

make sure that the pointer is referencing the allocated memory and that the memory is large enough to accommodate the string (remember about NULL terminating character!).

